# Hive RunTimeException NULL::character varying while doing HBaseIntegration

Tags: hive, hbase

I get the following error

`FAILED: RuntimeException java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: NULL::character varying`

when I try to select on a table in hive shell which is created using `'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'`.
On all the other tables that I create in hive, I can easily select over them. So my guess is that it has to do something with jar file related to HBaseStorageHandler.

```
CREATE TABLE hbase_table_emp(id int, name string, role string) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cf1:name,cf1:role")
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "emp");
```

I have been following this tutorial to accomplish my task : [HBaseHiveIntegration](http://hadooptutorial.info/hbase-integration-with-hive)

Versions: Hadoop 2.7.2 - Hive 2.1.0 - HBase 1.2.3

FYI this is not a duplicate to [hive-hbase integration throws classnotfoundexception NULL::character varying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37111398/hive-hbase-integration-throws-classnotfoundexception-nullcharacter-varying/) because his answer does not take into account, how we can solve this on a shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not fix this problem. I decided to change my Hive metastore from Postgresq to MySql and now it works.

In Postgresql when I made my schema I made sure that there is no Null casted  to character varying (NULL::character varying), but this did not resolve the issue.